# Changing Trim Size in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, resize

Because of a careless mistake, I have a 277-page book file with 12 chapters in separate files that has a trim size of 7.25x9.5".  It should be 7.5x9.25. There are 99 illustrations as anchored objects.  Most (over 80) have a caption that's a separate anchored object.

Is there a way to fix this that does not involve touching all 277 pages manually?

If, as I suspect, there is not, what can I do to make my life easier in the future?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to resize without at least *looking* at every page afterwards. Nothing should *move*. But with a missing .25" you may need to ensure bleeds and margins are acceptable. Sometimes, depending upon layout, reducing by .125" on each side isn't *that* bad. Depends upon the project.

And I don't believe there's anything you can do for the future other than ensure you set the correct trim size. (Or, if freelancing, inform client's there's a fee associated with resizing if they gave you the wrong trim size.)

Comment: Thanks.  (This was my own dumb mistake.)

Comment: There is theLiquid Layout feature... I don't know if that would be helpful. I've never actually used it here - just played with it to see if it was worthwhile in my work. Someone may come along with more info on that. I always found it unreliable and convoluted myself.

Comment: Offtopic answer, but when you're working with a 277 page doc, you kind of want to keep incremental backups, specifically because of accidental mistakes.